# Searching for term and range in same bool filter in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

My query is like:

```
query: {
    filtered: {
        filter: {
            bool: {
                must: [
                    range: {price: {gte: 222, lte: 1000}},
                    term: {city: Adana}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It returns empty result. But doing same using uri search (`_search?q=city:Adana` gives correct result.

Giving multiple range queries, like latitude and price works, but adding term fails.

What can be problem here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
query: {
    filtered: {
        filter: {
            bool: {
                must: [
                    { range: {price: {gte: 222, lte: 1000}} },
                    { term: {city: Adana} }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is some code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/7a4811d00e562f4d41e252ae5084ec78fa23d80f

Comment: Sorry, changed that in question. I use array_push so its already is an array. Its like ``0 => range => ...`` and ``1 => term => ...``

Comment: Oh, it's probably `term`, then. Is the `city` field analyzed? If so then the correct term is probably `adana`, so `Adana` won't match anything. Either change the analysis of that field in your mapping, or use the lower-case version as your search term. Or use a match query or something.

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved problem. The only problem for now is texts with empty spaces, but they can be splitter into one words very easy. Thanks again.

Comment: The filtered query has been deprecated and removed in ES 5.0.  
You can now use a bool query with an array in the filter.

    `query: {
      bool: {
        filter: [
          {
            match: {city: Adana}
          },
          {
            range: {price: {gte: 222, lte: 1000}}
          }
        ]
      }
    }`